# delete alphabetical symbols, but not

Tags: javascript

hy guys
I want to delete all letters/symbolsy from string, but not "."(dots)

I found this code:

```
.replace(/\D/g,'')
```

this code delte "." too, any idea?

for e.g. 129349.29ajhdnm2939

Comment: And do you want to remove digits?

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own group:

```
var result = someString.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
```

The character group `[^\d.]` means, "any character except digits and `.`". Now, understand that if "someString" is `hello 123.45.678 world`, you'll end up with something that's not a valid number because it has two `.` characters. If you want to make sure the result is a string of digits optionally followed by a `.` and another string of digits, you'd have to use a more complicated pattern:

```
var result = someString.replace(/^.*(\d+(?:\.\d*)?).*$/, "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

`.replace(/[^.]/g,'')`. Your pattern (`.replace(/\D/g,'')`) means everything except digits.